How to save DB tables summary shown in MySQL workbench
I can see DB table details in MySQL Workbench, but can't find an option to save them. I also tried CTRL + A and CTRL + C but it didn't selected all the rows.


I don't get why you would wish to save the result of a query , you could save the query and run as required. SQL isn't a reporting tool but if you want to snapshot data then write to a table.

@P.Salmon, This is not a query output. The left highlighted green box is the button provided by MySQL workbench. Upon clicking that button, you will get above output.

Hello Leaner: You can easily extract the DB tables summary. Just open-up SQL window, copy-paste the SQL and run.
SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE, VERSION, ROW_FORMAT, TABLE_ROWS, DATA_LENGTH, MAX_DATA_LENGTH, INDEX_LENGTH, 
DATA_FREE, AUTO_INCREMENT, CREATE_TIME, UPDATE_TIME, CHECK_TIME, TABLE_COLLATION, CHECKSUM, TABLE_COMMENT
FROM information_schema.Tables 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<your-database-name'

Once you get the result grid, you will be able to find export option (having icon of floppy disk). Click and save your result.
Let me know the update. Cheers.
Update:
Once you get the result grid, you will see the button Export. Just click on it, you will be able to save the result.


Thank you for the detailed query @Sujan. I was using only two columns SELECT table_name, table_rows ....
But is there is no way to save from the MySQL Workbench provided details?

Hi @learner, I have attached an image in the solution. You will be able to export the result. Good luck

Yes I know about this export option. I was still checking about the other view (Summary view) and to save that view.
In the image I've attached, if you click on the "i"  symbol, when you hover over DB on left panel (Green box highlighted), you will get the right side summary view.
